# Boot sequence gone after installation

Tags: boot

I was having glitches with my Windows 10, so I decided to install Ubuntu, and dump Windows for good. I'm a developer, and have an intermediate knowledge about computer support, but I've never worked with Linux.

After installing Ubuntu, the Boot sequence is gone. The BIOS can't find the HDD, CD-ROM, nor the GRUB Boot-loader, but it boots the live version from the USB. I tried that in my laptop, which is a DELL.

#### Update 1: This is the output of `efibootmgr -v`:

```
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0001
Boot0000* Ubuntu    HD(1,GPT, 378f89bd-304b-4d4b-8d0e-cb634d895e2c,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0001* UEFI: Lexar USB Flash Drive 1100        PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(1,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x28,0x800,0x74ff800)..BO
```

#### Update 2: I've found the answer here:

[How to Repair GRUB2 When Ubuntu Won’t Boot](https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/)

Comment: If you have an EFI system, run `efibootmgr -v` and [edit] the output into your question. Put four spaces at the start of each line to make the formatting work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output of `efibootmgr -v`, it looks like you just need to go into your UEFI setup and put Ubuntu at the top of the boot sequence.

However, I'm not sure where the CD and HDD options might have gone, or how to get them back.

Comment: And that's the thing; I go to my BIOS, and there's nothing there. The GRUB Bootloader is not even there to put it at the top.

Comment: Oh, I see. Is there an option to add a boot entry?

Comment: You could try using `efibootmgr` to add a boot option (see [instructions on Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#efibootmgr)), but the issue might be that you have to disable SecureBoot or something - I'm not sure.

Comment: There were options to add boot sequence in my BIOS. You were right; my BIOS had the SecureBoot on; I turned it off. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @ShadowCrow So it's working now?

Comment: Yes, after I applied the graphical solution suggested in the link that I've left in the post that started this thread; Ubuntu works correctly now. Thanks for being there for me. I appreciate it. :)